# User names wrapped too early in chat transcript (mobile chat version)

Tags: bug, design, chat, mobile-web, chat-transcript

On the [chat transcript page](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89), usernames are split to several lines for unknown reasons, despite there being enough space on the single line:

> [image]

After joining the chat, all names fit in line:

> [image]

Interesting moment that even page refresh can fix the issue:

> [image]

Google Chrome, iPadOS 17.3, iPad Pro 11"

Comment: No repro with Chrome under Windows in a desktop PC, even when emulating mobile and small screen.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda No, that's definitely the mobile version of the chat transcript. That's something you can verify for yourself by just switching modes. In addition, at the top of the transcript page in the GIF, the button to switch to the "full site" is clearly visible.

Comment: @Makyen I did check and something looked different, but yeah on deeper look you're correct. Anyway, still no repro for me.